# How do to plot this below values that all categorical values on y axis come in same value as of Xaxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, chart.js, apexcharts

[error image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0czP.png)
**dummy arrays example :**
**plant_arr = ["abc","dbc","asd"]**
**opr_no_arr = ["company1","company2","company3"]**
**draft_arr = [0:{x:"abc",y:"comapny1"},1:{x:"bds",y:"comapny2"},2:{x:"dbc",y:"comapny3"}]**
Pending For Creation = [0:{x:"abc",y:"comapny1"},1:{x:"bds",y:"comapny2"},2:{x:"dbc",y:"comapny3"}]
Created = [0:{x:"abc",y:"comapny1"},1:{x:"bds",y:"comapny2"},2:{x:"dbc",y:"comapny3"}]

```
        name: "Pending For Creation",
        data: draft_arr,
        color:"#000000"
      },{
        name: "Created",
        data: created_arr,
        color:'#FF0000'
      },{
        name: "Execution In Progress",
        data: execution_arr,
        color:'#FFAE42'
      },
      {
        name: "Completed",
        data: completed_arr,
        color:'#28a745'
      }],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'scatter',
        zoom: {
          enabled: true,
          type: 'xy'
        },
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'category',
        //tickAmount: 10,
        categories: plant_arr,
      }, this is working 
      yaxis:
        {
          //type: 'category',
          // tickAmount:1,
          // categories : opr_no_arr,
          labels: {
            maxWidth: "auto",
            formatter: (val : string, index) => opr_no_arr[index], //error cant show particaular labels 
          }, 
          title: {
            text: "OPR",
            style: {
              colors: "#000000"
            }
          }
        },
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "right"
      }
    };
    this.first_chartRef = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('first'), chartOptions);
    this.first_chartRef.render();
 }
```

[this the image of the output red line are output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7muyh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yaxis:
{
type: 'category',
tickAmount:6,
categories : opr_no_arr,
labels: {
maxWidth: "auto",
},
} keep it like this and check ?